# How to convert LaserScanner msgs to 2D cartesian cooridnates?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert LaserScanner msgs to 2D vector(cartesian coordinates,(X,Y) pair) in C++ without using any library.Main problem is that I'm using a formula X=r*cos(phi)  and Y=r*sin(phi),and if ranges[i] is r,how can I find phi?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212754/how-to-convert-laserscanner-msgs-to-2d-cartesian-cooridnates?/) by [ANY](https://answers.ros.org/users/22379/any/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The information is in the LaserScan message. You can angle_min for the start angle, and each range is angle_increment * i + angle_min for the phi.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3